# Scattering theory with two Dirac potentials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, scattering, dirac-delta-distributions

i am trying to solve a toy model as a scattering problem containing two Dirac potentials $V(x) = u \delta(x) + u \delta(x-L)$  placed at $x=0$ and $x=L$. My main aim is to find resonance energy states in between these barrier regions and then calculate the density of states around a given resonant level.  My question is, can i get  resonant
 energy (or wave-vector) values that are not evenly spaced? I plotted the total transmission as a function of energy and saw spikes in the graph that were not evenly spaced and didn't had the same amplitude?

Comment: My gut feeling is that yes, the spectrum will almost certainly be unevenly spaced because there is tunnelling outside the region between the two Dirac potentials. In such a case, you get a transcendental eigenvalue equation. If you think of the approximation to the problem - two rect function spikes - you've certainly got a transcendental eigenvalue equation and uneven spectrum. It's been a long time since i've done this problem, but i seem to recall that the tunnelling remains in the limit. as the rects become infinitely thin and high. Evenly space spectrums arise when there is no ....

Comment: ... tunnelling and zeros in the wavefunction are forced at the edges, as in the infinite well potential. THat's a very special situation.

Comment: @SeleneRoutley Thanks for the comment. yes, i do get a trancendental equation which looks very ugly. It seems that finding density of states will be a little complex computationally.

Answer (score 2):

The resonances' wavenumbers $k_n$  should obey the Fabry-Perot condition
$$
k_n = \frac{2\pi n}{2L}, \quad n\in {\mathbb Z}.
$$
The widths of the resonances will depend on $k$ because the reflectivity of the individual $\delta$ potentials are $k$ dependent --- but the change with $k$ should be smooth. Your irregularity suggest that you have made an error. What expression do you have (and are plotting) for transmission coeficient $t(k)$? I vaguely remember that the denominator has a factor of $(1-|r|^2 e^{2ik L})$ where $r(k)$ is the reflection coef of a single delta potential.

you have 
$$T(k) = \frac{1}{(1+\frac{a^2(cos(2kL)-1)}{k^2})^2 + (\frac{2a}{k}+\frac{a^2sin(2kL)}{k^2})^2}
$$

For the equation
$$
[-\partial_x^2 +\lambda\delta(x)+ \lambda \delta(x-L)]\psi=E \psi
$$
I get
$$
|t|^2 = \frac{16 k^2}{|4k^2-4i k \lambda -\lambda^2 +\lambda^2 e^{-2i kL}|^2}
$$
so for $\lambda\gg k$ (high finesse) we have maxima near $1-e^{2ikL}=0$. As $k$ gets larger the reflectivity of the potentials decreases and the resonances move to complex $k$, as expected.  At large $k$ there is negligible reflection and $|t|^2\to 1$. Did you plot for  large and small finesse?

Comment: well, i was expecting an expression of this sort for the transmission coefficient that goes to maximum at k values which are similar to the one you have written, but they do not.

Comment: Could you write out your expression?

Comment: T(k) = \frac{1}{(1+\frac{a^2(cos(2kL)-1)}{k^2})^2 + (\frac{2a}{k}+\frac{a^2sin(2kL)}{k^2})^2}. This is for the Transmission

Comment: I'll compare it with my own calculation.

Comment: i forgot to mention. here  a= (m*u)*2*pi/h

Comment: a =  (m*u)*(2*pi)^2/(h)^2

Comment: I added a bit to my answer including what I get for the transmision probablility.  I have not had time to make plots.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on resonances being moved to complex  k values?

Comment: Its the usual thing, If the mirrors are not perfectly relecting, any waves trapped between the mirrors will eventualy leak out and so the time dependence $e^{-iEt}$ must decay, meaning that $E$ (and hence $k$) has an imaginary part.  Thus the value of $k$ at which the  the denominator in $T$  takes its minimum value (the location of the resonance) is away from the real axis.